# Turn Koeppen Climate Legend into meaningful csv with regex

Tags: r, regex

I have this table:

```
    1:  Af   Tropical, rainforest                  [0 0 255]
    2:  Am   Tropical, monsoon                     [0 120 255]
    3:  Aw   Tropical, savannah                    [70 170 250]
    4:  BWh  Arid, desert, hot                     [255 0 0]
    5:  BWk  Arid, desert, cold                    [255 150 150]
    6:  BSh  Arid, steppe, hot                     [245 165 0]
    7:  BSk  Arid, steppe, cold                    [255 220 100]
    8:  Csa  Temperate, dry summer, hot summer     [255 255 0]
    9:  Csb  Temperate, dry summer, warm summer    [200 200 0]
    10: Csc  Temperate, dry summer, cold summer    [150 150 0]
    11: Cwa  Temperate, dry winter, hot summer     [150 255 150]
    12: Cwb  Temperate, dry winter, warm summer    [100 200 100]
    13: Cwc  Temperate, dry winter, cold summer    [50 150 50]
    14: Cfa  Temperate, no dry season, hot summer  [200 255 80]
    15: Cfb  Temperate, no dry season, warm summer [100 255 80]
    16: Cfc  Temperate, no dry season, cold summer [50 200 0]
    17: Dsa  Cold, dry summer, hot summer          [255 0 255]
    18: Dsb  Cold, dry summer, warm summer         [200 0 200]
    19: Dsc  Cold, dry summer, cold summer         [150 50 150]
    20: Dsd  Cold, dry summer, very cold winter    [150 100 150]
    21: Dwa  Cold, dry winter, hot summer          [170 175 255]
    22: Dwb  Cold, dry winter, warm summer         [90 120 220]
    23: Dwc  Cold, dry winter, cold summer         [75 80 180]
    24: Dwd  Cold, dry winter, very cold winter    [50 0 135]
    25: Dfa  Cold, no dry season, hot summer       [0 255 255]
    26: Dfb  Cold, no dry season, warm summer      [55 200 255]
    27: Dfc  Cold, no dry season, cold summer      [0 125 125]
    28: Dfd  Cold, no dry season, very cold winter [0 70 95]
    29: ET   Polar, tundra                         [178 178 178]
    30: EF   Polar, frost                          [102 102 102]
```

First: It is really hard to get this into a csv...
I would like to have the code (first column) and the long description (e.g. `Tropical, rainforest` for the first row). So I thought I would handle this with a regex. But apparently I am hitting my understanding of how regexes work. I tried doing it in `R`, but I'd be super grateful for any help.

I tried something like this:

`str_match(a, "\\d{1,2}:\\s[a-zA-Z]{2,3}.*([a-zA-Z,]).*\\[")` but it fails...

Comment: Maybe `str_match(a, "(\\d{1,2}):\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\[(.*)\\]")`?

Comment: Maybe have also a look at `read.fwf` *Read Fixed Width Format Files*.

Comment: Or, `(\\d{1,2}):\\s*(\\w+)\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\[(.*)\\]`... See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L6ufhj/1).

Comment: wow haha, thank you so so much!! I will definitely watch your regex quickies course:)

Comment: You refer to your data as a table, what is the original format? The solution might start with reading it in a different way, which might prevent the need of fixing the data afterwards in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use either

```r
str_match(a, "(\\d{1,2}):\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\[(.*)\\]")
str_match(a, "(\\d{1,2}):\\s*(\\w+)\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\[(.*)\\]")
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/L6ufhj/2) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/L6ufhj/1).

*Details*:

- `(\d{1,2})` - Group 1: one or two digits
- `:\s*` - `:` and zero or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 2: one or more letters, digits or `_`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\[` -  a `[` char
- `(.*)` - Group 4: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\]` -  a `]` char.

Answer (score 1):

Prepared an [example](https://regex101.com/r/h2Jn1v/1/), right? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptCIU.png)
Since the data contains commas, made tab delimiters

```
const regex = /(\d+): +\w+ +([^\[]+).*/gm;
const str = `    
    1:  Af   Tropical, rainforest                  [0 0 255]
    2:  Am   Tropical, monsoon                     [0 120 255]
    3:  Aw   Tropical, savannah                    [70 170 250]
    8:  Csa  Temperate, dry summer, hot summer     [255 255 0]
    9:  Csb  Temperate, dry summer, warm summer    [200 200 0]
    10: Csc  Temperate, dry summer, cold summer    [150 150 0]
    11: Cwa  Temperate, dry winter, hot summer     [150 255 150]`;
const subst = `$1\t$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```